# Overlay view added by Window Manager hides keyboard (Android)

Tags: android, keyboard, overlay

I added a view to the Window Manager, an overlay button wich I can drag arround, but at the time that any kind of text input is needed, the keyboard just doesn't pop up like it used to be. This only works when I remove that view. It's a button added by a service with the following LayoutParams  :

```
     params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            button_size, button_size,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            , PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
     params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
```

I did some research and I also tried to add this to the Android Manifest:

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

But this didn't work either.

Since I didn't find any related questions/answers, can someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it by adding

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
```

to the LayoutParams flags.

Comment: are you able to do backpressed when this param is added in Window manager ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ hardware key events are passed to the content behind the overlay by default and you do not gain focus in this mode. You can assign a touch interceptor on the EditText that updates the parameter to "FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL"  to allow use, but it will require a way to restore the flag upon completion. You can get more details at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, 
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

This put the added view behind the keyboard.